# Can anyone explain this dependent probability statement.

Tags: probability

I have never asked a question and I'm totally a newbie here.

There are 10 M&Ms left in the bag: 5 are green, and 5 are blue. What are the odds of getting 3 blue candies in a row? The probability of getting the first blue candy is 5/10, or 1/2. When we pick a blue candy, though, we remove it from the bag, so the probability of getting another is 4/9. The probability of picking a third blue candy is 3/8. This means our final probability is 1/2 * 4/9 * 3/8, or .0833. So, there is an 8.3% chance of picking three blue candies in a row.

Why is the probability of getting the first blue candy 5/10 or 1/2?? I can't understand. Similarly why is second one 4/9 and third one 3/8??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically just how the number of blue candies divided by the total number of candies.

I think you understand the calculation, so let's go into some examples. Assume you are picking candies, and the bag has 1 blue and 1 green candy. What is your probability now? It would be 1/2.

Now assume that I added in another blue candy, your probability would increase. In fact, it would increase to 2/3. The reason being there are 2 blue candies out of 3 total candies.

Probabilities are actually just a way of saying that over countless experiments that we do, we would expect to see 2/3 candies being blue. Which in this case is self-explanatory , since there are only 2 out of 3 blue candies. But I hope you can understand this short explanation.

And of course, going back to the question. After you take out 1 blue candy, there are 4 blue candies out of the 9 remaining candies. Hence, the probability would be 4/9 and 3/8 respectively.

And you multiply them because you want all of them to happen, which you will see makes the probability get lower and lower, since probabilities are in this case all less than 1.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad you understand the explanation.